# How to insert saved Looped array into MYSQL table using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop, prepared-statement

Having trouble getting converted Data to insert into table. Below is code for how I gathered data.

```
  <?php
  session_start();

  $mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost', 'db', 'password', 'username');  

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT bday FROM uploaded");
  $stmt->bind_result($bday);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
```

Now I  use while loop and convert birth date to age.

```
 while ($stmt->fetch()){ 
     $birthDate = $bday;
     $birthDate = explode("/", $birthDate);
     $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2])))>  
     date("md") ? ((date("Y") - $birthDate[2]) - 1 ): (date("Y") - $birthDate[2]));

   Save results to my Array

  $result_bday = array($age);

  } // end loop
```

Partial results print_r. Note that Arrays not numbered for each row or birth date. Should be [0] [1] [2] etc... ??

```
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($result_bday);
  echo '</pre>';

  Array([0] => 32)
  Array([0] => 46)
  Array([0] => 19)
```

works perfect to this point. Cant seem to get insert to work. code below

```
  $stmt=$mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `converted` (`age`) VALUES (?)');        
  $stmt->bind_param( 'i' , $age);   
    foreach($result_bday as $i => $row){        
    list($age)=$row;  
    $stmt->execute();        
}
```

Comment: 1) you missed single quote for `'username'` 2) if you want `$result_bday` to return [0],[1] then you have to use `$result_bday[] = $age;`

Comment: Missed quote is typo when I posted here.. Insert remains mystery